Restore ReFS partition deleted by mistake
I'm facing an issue where a ReFS partition has been mistakenly deleted, and I need to restore it.
I've attempted to recover the partition using MiniTools Partition Wizard, but it couldn't locate the partition. Additionally, I tried using EaseUS Partition Wizard, which also failed to find it. I then attempted recovery with WinHex, but unfortunately, it too couldn't locate the partition.
However, upon exploring the disk with Hxd, I found that the data still exists, including the partition header, file names, and contents.
Any guidance on how to proceed with the recovery would be greatly appreciated.

If it's only about a deleted partition (i.e. not a deleted filesystem, not a deleted partition table), then it should be enough to restore the entry in the partition table with the exact values that used to be there. Sometimes an educated guess may help. See this answer for some insight. What is your current partition table? Do you remember where (e.g. between what other partitions) the partition in question used to be? At what sector did you find the "partition header"? (There is no such thing, do you mean "filesystem header"?)

It is GPT, Yes I know where was the partition its space is now shown as unallocated.

sorry yes its file system header

Thanks @JoepvanSteen It works

As Joep van Steen mentioned, DMDE software offers full support for ReFS, allowing me to successfully restore files using it
